# Why does my code give this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginning Python programmer, and I just finished my first program, Battle.
But I'm having a problem. As far as I can see, all the code works fine except for one part near the end, where I get an `UnboundLocalError`, take a look:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[Dir]\Programs\Battle.py", line 210, in <module>
callUserCombat()
File "[Dir]\Programs\Battle.py", line 26, in callUserCombat
playerLeft = str(playerLeft)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'playerLeft' referenced before assignment
```

And this is what it's referring to (no small amount, sorry):

```
#Define callUserCombat().
def callUserCombat():
    print('Your turn.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print()
    print('Choose a move:')
    print('Attack 1 [2 - 3 Damage] (1)')
    print('Attack 2 [0 - 5 Damage] (2)')
    print('Heal [Heals 0 - 6] (3)')
    playerLeft = str(playerLeft)
    enemyLeft = str(enemyLeft)
    print('Your HP: ' + playerLeft)
    print('Enemy HP: ' + enemyLeft)
    chosenAttack = input()

    while chosenAttack != '0':
        if chosenAttack == '1':
            chosenAttackPower = random.randint(2,3)
            enemyLeft = - chosenAttackPower
            chosenAttackPower = str(chosenAttackPower)
            print('You attacked!')
            print('Enemy lost ' + chosenAttackPower + 'HP. ')
            break

        if chosenAttack == '2':
            chosenAttackPower = random.randint(0,5)
            enemyLeft = - chosenAttackPower
            chosenAttackPower = str(ChosenAttackPower)
            print('You attacked!')
            print("Enemy lost " + chosenAttackPower + 'HP. ')
            break

        if chosenAttack == '3':
            chosenAttackPower = random.randint(1,5) 
            playerLeft = + chosenAttackPower
            chosenAttackPower = str(ChosenAttackPower)
            print('You healed!')
            print('Healed ' + chosenAttackPower + 'HP.')
            break

        else:
            chosenAttack = '0'
            print('Please enter a valid move code.')
            print("Attack 1 (1)")
            print("Attack 2 (2)")
            print("Heal (3)")
            print()
            chosenAttack = input()
        limitHealth()

#Define callEnemyCombat().
def callEnemyCombat():
    print('Enemy\'s turn.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print()
    enemyAttack = random.randint(1,6)
    if enemyAttack == '1':
        enemyAttackPower = random.randint(2,3)
        playerLeft = - enemyAttackPower
        enemyAttackPower = str(enemyAttackPower)
        print('Don\'t bother taunting me, you\'ll die trying. And it\'s mean.')
        print('Enemy attacked!')
        print('You lost ' + enemyAttackPower + 'HP. ')

    if enemyAttack == '2':
        enemyAttackPower = random.randint(2,3)
        playerLeft = - enemyAttackPower
        enemyAttackPower = str(enemyAttackPower)
        print('Where do you live? I only want to know so I can kill')
        print('your family once I\'m finished with you.')
        print('Enemy attacked!')
        print('You lost ' + enemyAttackPower + 'HP. ')

    if enemyAttack == '3':
        enemyAttackPower = random.randint(2,3)
        playerLeft = - enemyAttackPower
        enemyAttackPower = str(enemyAttackPower)
        print('I can take anything you can throw at me. Except Chocolate.')
        print('I\'m allergic to Chocolate.')
        print('Enemy attacked!')
        print('You lost ' + enemyAttackPower + 'HP. ')

    if enemyAttack == '4':
        enemyAttackPower = random.randint(0,5)
        playerLeft = - enemyAttackPower
        enemyAttackPower = str(enemyAttackPower)
        print('I WILL kill you, even if I have to hire the Men in Black to do it.')
        print('Enemy attacked!')
        print('You lost ' + enemyAttackPower + 'HP. ')

    if enemyAttack == '5':
        enemyAttackPower = random.randint(0,5)
        playerLeft = - enemyAttackPower
        enemyAttackPower = str(enemyAttackPower)
        print('Have you heard of pong? We could play pong after I kill you,')
        print('if you like.')
        print('Enemy attacked!')
        print('You lost ' + enemyAttackPower + 'HP. ')

    if enemyAttack == '6':
        enemyAttackPower = random.randint(1,5) 
        enemyLeft = + enemyAttackPower
        enemyAttackPower = str(ChosenAttackPower)
        print('Charging up with a cold glass of water, and a side of you.')
        print('Enemy healed!')
        print('Healed ' + chosenAttackPower + 'HP.')
    limitHealth()

#Define limitHealth().
def limitHealth():
    if playerLeft > playerHealth:
        playerLeft = playerHealth

    if enemyLeft > enemyHealth:
        enemyLeft = enemyHealth
```

And here is the code, so all that makes sense:
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/9l4ifgmk5sx1pg1/Battle.py).

EDITED: Sorry about the post, it seemed to be quite terribly written, so I fixed.

Comment: Please extract the relevant pieces of your code where the error occurs (+- 5-7 lines) and include it into your question.

Comment: There is a `playerLeft` which is defined at the _module_ level but not in the function - looks like a scoping issue?...

Comment: @Basic you can write the answer. I deleted mine. Don't want to take your credit.

Answer (score 2):

It's a scope variable problem. You need to type your globals variables as such :

```
enemyHealth = 1
playerLeft = 2
enemyLeft = 2
...

#Define callUserCombat().
def callUserCombat():
     global enemyHealth
     global playerLeft 
     global enemyLeft 
     etc.
```

Comment: The answer solves the problem, but rewriting the code without using `global` would be the better option.

Comment: I dont think it's a scope problem. Because I've run some code without  using `global`. http://pastie.org/7723221#2 . I used `SPROUT = '@'` without using `global`
`

Comment: @Matthias : I just answered OP question "Why does my code give this error?". But I agree with you : mutable globals are dangerous.

Comment: @Moj note in the `SPROUT` example, you are not trying to assign SPROUT from inside your class / function, you are simply referencing it. If you tried to reassign a new copy of it like: `SPROUT = SPROUT + 'yuck!'` you would also get the UnboundLocalVariable exception

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys :) So I just have to redefine the variables as global in the def statment?

Answer (score 0):

definitely an issue with scope, and more specifically the way in which python resolves names when attempting to assign to it (i.e. when you're trying to assign the variable `playerLeft`). You can look here: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/ for a full description.

Since it seems that you are simply trying to print the value of the global variable, `playerLeft`. Simply do that, exactly:

```
playerLeft = 2
enemyLeft = 2
...

#Define callUserCombat().
def callUserCombat():

    ...
    print('Your HP: ', playerLeft) 
    print('Enemy HP: ',  enemyLeft) 

    ...
```

Should avoid the problem